# Can I use intellisense for CSS in ASP.net 2010?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I've just installed Visual Studio 2010, but I cant seem to manage to get intellisense working to suggest classes.

Comment: We will need more information than that. Post code where intellisense doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, intellisense for CSS does work in ASP.net 2010,  so if it's not for you then you have an install or configuration problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to try and click "ctrl+space" to force intellisense

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple .aspx webform, drag and drop from the solution explorer the .css file. Go to source view and write something like this:

```
<span class="
```

then normally you should get intellisense. Same goes for the CssClass properties for server controls.

If you however try to include your .css file in a dynamic way by code then you could end up not getting intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside to the same issue.
If you are using ReSharper to enhance the intellisense, you may have to reinstall it to update the VS2010.